# How to use Polymorphism in php for design oriented apps?

Tags: php, oop, polymorphism

I'm trying to use `OOP` in my plugins. The plugin functionality is mostly design oriented, let say if user choose a triangle shape in back end then i should output a div with triangle shape, there are many predefined shapes like this. I have to write different `width,height,border-radius` etc.  The plugin also has animation feature so i need to check whether animation is checked on,if so then i should check for which kind of animation and then from where to where(left to right or right to left) etc.

The thing is this involves more conditions. Many People, Blog and Author say we need Polymorphism when there is **more conditional statements**.

Here is the sample of my problem. Options used in here are just for sample, I take options from DB. There are javascript functions too. Based on the user options i output different javascript code.

```
<?php

class test {

    function __construct($color, $place, $border, $bordercolor) {
        $this->color = $color;
        $this->place = $place;
        $this->enable_border = $border;
        $this->border_color = $bordercolor;
    }

    function output() {
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            #test{
                width:150px;
                height:150px;
                position:absolute;
                background-color: <?php echo $this->color; ?>;
                <?php
                if ($this->place == "TopLeft") {
                    echo "left:0px;";
                    echo "top:0px;";
                } elseif ($this->place == "BottomLeft") {
                    echo "left:0px;";
                    echo "Bottom:0px;";
                } elseif ($this->place == "TopRight") {
                    echo "right:0px;";
                    echo "top:0px;";
                } elseif ($this->place == "BottomRight") {
                    echo "right:0px;";
                    echo "Bottom:0px;";
                }
                //for border
                if ($this->enable_border == "Yes") {
                    echo "border:2px solid $this->border_color;";
                }
                ?>
            }
        </style>
        <div id="test">
            Sample Content
        </div>
        <?php
    }

}

$obj = new test("red", "BottomRight", "Yes", "black");
$obj->output();
?>
```

What should i do now. Should i use polymorphism? If so then i have to create so many implementing class this is same as conditional code. What is the difference?

Can anybody give a sample solution to this problem using polymorphism. Am i heading in a right direction? Any help would be appreiciated

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good practice to simplify method code by refactoring out additional responsibilities. The code below moves the position styles output to seperate classes, by means of a Template Pattern. The resulting body of output function is half it's original size and contains much less logic. Now u can add, remove or change new subtypes of Place independently of the output function.

```
<?php

// template pattern
abstract class Place {
    public abstract function css();
}

class TopLeft extends Place {
    public function css() {
       echo "left:0px;";
       echo "top:0px;";
    }
}
class BottomLeft extends Place {
    public function css() {
       echo "left:0px;";
       echo "Bottom:0px;";
    }
}
class TopRight extends Place {
    public function css() {
       echo "right:0px;";
       echo "top:0px;";
    }
}
class BottomRight extends Place {
    public function css() {
       echo "right:0px;";
       echo "Bottom:0px;";
    }
}

class test {

function __construct($color, $place, $border, $bordercolor) {
    $this->color = $color;
    $this->place = $place;
    $this->enable_border = $border;
    $this->border_color = $bordercolor;
}

function output() {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        #test{
            width:150px;
            height:150px;
            position:absolute;
            background-color: <?php echo $this->color; ?>;
            <?php $this->place.css(); ?>
            //for border
            if ($this->enable_border == "Yes") {
                echo "border:2px solid $this->border_color;";
            }
            ?>
        }
    </style>
    <div id="test">
        Sample Content
    </div>
    <?php
}

$obj = new test("red", new BottomRight(), "Yes", "black");
$obj->output();
?>
```

However, we are not there yet ;).

Comment: Thanks for your help +1. Is there any different or advantage in using this?

Comment: It is easier to scale out with eg TopCenter subtype and easier to unittest, and u can implement different formating eg PDF Easily!?!

Comment: Don't get it bad. Is this the correct way? still i see lot of code involved than previous conditional logic. I have animation and border types too. Let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly, we are not there yet. Next thing you can try is to transform the test class to a builder with separate calls for each css style eg setWidth, setBorder etc, these methods could return the builder instanse to enable fluent syntax too

Comment: Looks interesting, any example please

Comment: I ll leave that you as an excercise ;)